# hibernate criteria

Tags: hibernate

Is it possible to define HIbernate criteria without having relationship between tables.

Regards,
Raj

Comment: You must provide much more context. Which OS, which platform/language?

Answer (score 4):

The Criteria Api requires your tables to be mapped to Entity Classes.